# Create search bar for json API using just javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, opendata

I am trying to create a search bar that will show the names of schools that I've gotten from an Open Data API when their name is typed.

API:

```
[ {
  "address" : "123 Street",
  "name" : "First School ....",
  "website" : {
    "url" : 
       "http://......."
  }
}
, {
  "address" : "123 Bay",
  "name" : "Second School ....",
  "website" : {
    "url" : 
       "http://......."
  }
}   ....etc
```

What I want is if I input the word "first" in my search bar just First School will appear.

So far in my html when I click the Search button it changes my URL but every school name is always showing. Im not sure what my next step is ... ?

Thanks for your time.

My .js file:

```
let name = 'name'; 
const api = 'https...api website... .json' +
                `$where=name LIKE '%${name}%'` +
                '&$order=name';
const url = encodeURI(api);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",load);

function load(){

    fetch('https:....api website... .json')
        .then(function(result) {
            return result.json(); 
        })
        .then(function(data) {  
            listSchools(data);
        });
}

function listSchools(schoolData){

    let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    let footer = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
    let input = document.getElementById('input');   //id from HTML

    for(let i = 0; i<schoolData.length; i++){
        let keys = Object.keys(schoolData[i]);
        let values = Object.values(schoolData[i]);

        let section = document.createElement("section");
        let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        let ul = document.createElement("ul");

        h1.innerHTML = `${schoolData[i].name}`;
        section.appendChild(h1);
        section.appendChild(ul);
        body.insertBefore(section, footer); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Im not sure that u need to use VanillaJS or allow to use other library, But it would be easily by using `ajax` combine with `select2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: You can take the filter term on click of search button and search for it in the html h1 tags. If you do find it then return with the first match and append it to the document.

```
 let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    let footer = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
    let input = document.getElementById('input');   //id from HTML
    let button = document.getElementById('btn'); //search button
        
    button.addEventListener('click',() => filterList(input.value));
 
    function listSchools(schoolData){
    for(let i = 0; i<schoolData.length; i++){
        let keys = Object.keys(schoolData[i]);
        let values = Object.values(schoolData[i]);

        let section = document.createElement("section");
        let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        let ul = document.createElement("ul");

        h1.innerHTML = `${schoolData[i].name}`;
        section.appendChild(h1);
        section.appendChild(ul);
        body.insertBefore(section, footer); 
    }
   }
    
      function filterList(filterTerm){
        const h1Tags = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
           let filteredh1;
           for(const h1 of h1Tags){
           if (h1.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filterTerm.toLowerCase())){
               document.body.innerHTML = '';
               filteredh1=h1
               break;
           }
        }
           if(filteredh1 !== undefined){
             let section = document.createElement("section");
             let newh1= document.createElement("h1");
             let newul= document.createElement("ul");
             newh1.innerHTML = filteredh1.textContent
             section.appendChild(newh1);
             section.appendChild(newul);
             body.appendChild(input);
             body.appendChild(button);
             body.insertBefore(section, footer); 
           }
           else {
             let errorMessage = document.createElement("h1")
             errorMessage.innerHTML = "Not found"
             body.appendChild(errorMessage)
           }
       
       }
```

Comment: would this all be in my listSchools() function? or should i completely get rid of that.

Comment: Edited the answer to include listSchools() function.

Comment: The listSchools() function will list the schools. The filterTerm() function will only show the search term if found. So you need to keep both.